Does the pytorch model support parallelism?
Is it possible to deploy a pytorch model using fastapi to support multiple concurrency?
Or is it not possible to support concurrency because pytorch models operate synchronously?
If fastapi can't support it directly, what would it take to support it?
To know if it's possible to

Using async endpoints in FastAPI ensures that the execution of the function (containing the logic of the endpoint) does not block the current thread. FastAPI also internally uses an asyncio loop. See this Reddit thread for more explanation.

It depends on what you mean by concurrency. You can start a fastapi server with multiple workers where each worker has a copy of the model. You might be able to share the model between workers, but it looks like there could be issues. In either case, that setup could serve concurrent users with each server worker processing one request at a time. If you want batch inference with a single model instance, you need dynamic batching. Look into pytriton
